# @Query in JPA throwing null pointer exception

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I am getting nullPointerException from my custom jpa method findShiftNameById() in my shift planner project(github link below). I have used @Query annotation inside ShiftDetailsRepo Interface to implement the method. Please check and let me know what could be causing this. I tried by removing nativeQuery parameter but that gives shift_details not mapped error.I tried by changing datatypes between int and long and also by changing sd.shiftName to sd.shift_name(as per the column name that is available in my actual database) but still same nullPointerException error is coming.

Github link-https://github.com/Anupam5713/shiftPlannerAPI
The method is being called in the ShiftPlanService Class inside the service package

Is there something wrong in my query?

```
@Query(value = "select sd.shiftName from shift_details sd where sd.shiftId=:shiftId",nativeQuery=true)
    public String findShiftNameById(@Param("shiftId") int shiftId);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is the cause of NPE.  The call to sdr is done before the dependencies are wired.

```
@Service
public class ShiftPlanService {

    @Autowired
    ShiftDetailsRepo sdr;
    String S1 = sdr.findShiftNameById(1);
    String S2 = sdr.findShiftNameById(2);
```

Move these initializations to a @PostConstruct method.

Example

```
@PostConstruct
public void initDetails() {
    S1 = sdr.findShiftNameById(1);
    S2 = sdr.findShiftNameById(2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, According to your reasoning "The call to sdr is done before the dependencies are wired.", how do we know whether the dependencies are wired yet or not? By call to sdr,you mean the call to findShiftNameById(),right?

Comment: The wiring of dependencies happen at a particular point of bean initialization and you may please go through this document for more [info](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/spring-bean-life-cycle-example/) .Basically , the container creates a java instance and then the dependencies are wired. In your code , the dependency is used prior to this and it was null , resulting in an NPE .Yes , I meant the call to findShiftNameById().